# I need an analysis book that goes from basics to advanced through metric spaces and measure theory.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, book-recommendation

I've just graduated in physics and I intend to do a master's and doctorate in mathematical physics, but I don't have anyone to guide me in this path and I'm studying as a self-taught. When looking into the math needed for this with an expert in the field he told me that I would need to know functional analysis, topology and probability (it would be something on the levels of Reed and Simons, Munkres and Varadhan respectively). It's just that I left a course with a weak mathematical foundation and I'm reviewing linear algebra and calculus, and when researching more about functional analysis, topology and probability I realized that to understand well I need to have deep knowledge of analysis, real analysis, metric spaces, measure theory and maybe even other content that I don't even know exists yet. So I'm here looking for a recommendation for an analysis book that I can study on my own that covers everything from zero on analysis to advanced real analysis and explains metric spaces and measure theory. Is there any book or set of books that can help me with this?

I already bought some analysis books to study based on colleagues' comments but I still don't feel safe, some of them are:

-Principles of Mathematical Analysis and Real and Complex Analysis: Affordable Edition by Walter Rudin;

-Real Analysis 1, 2 and 3 and Analysis Course 1 and 2 by Elon Lages Lima;

-Analysis I by Djairo Guedes de Figueredo;

-Real Analysis - Functions of One Real Variable of Bourchtein and Bourchtein;

-Mauritius Zahn's Real Analysis;

-Introduction to Mathematical Analysis by Geraldo Ávila.

Comment: What do you mean by "I still don't feel safe"?

Comment: The two books by rudin are great, but the second maybe a bit advanced. I like Folland's book "Real analysis".

Comment: The two volume analysis course by Elon Lages Lima is very nice. The first volume is on functions of one real variable, while the second is on functions on $\mathbb{R}^N$. I'd recommend reading the second volume and checking the first as you need to, because most of the content is just a generalization of the things proven in the first volume. It has a really nice and clear exposition on differentiability and goes on to add something with morse theory; then it ends with an introduction to measure theory so it can talk about integrations on manifolds

Comment: @KCd It means I'm not sure they give me all the knowledge I need about analysis.

Comment: @PhoemueX But is it possible to start studying analysis starting from Principles of Mathematical Analysis and go to Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and then complete it with Folland's book? Would that give me all the knowledge I need and about measure theory and metric spaces? And is it possible for a self-taught person?

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Mas será que juntando todos os volumes do Elon contém desde a análise básica até a parte da análise real mais a teoria da medida e espaços métricos?

Comment: @ContaDoFDP os dois volumes são intendidos como um curso completo de análise real; eu diria que é bastante completo e vai desde o mais básico e fala bastante sobre teoria da medida. Se sentires que é insuficiente e quiseres coisas na mesma onda, aconselho outro livro dele esse sim completamente sobre espaços métricos (tendo isso por nome)

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Muito obrigado. Já ouvi por um professor sobre o livro de Espaços métricos do Elon, mas o meu professor disse que é um livro de difícil leitura. Você já leu ele? Você achou difícil a leitura dele?

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this looking for the same thing, you might try The Math You Need by Thomas Mack, which is what you describe, it's dense (Bourbaki style) but comprehensive:
https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262546324/the-math-you-need/

Sadly it won't be out till October 2023.

Comment: @ContaDoFDP eu usei-o como referência numa cadeira de topologia. Tendo estudado já o segundo volume de análises e com o apoio da cadeira que estava a ter, não senti dificuldade, mas pode definitivamente ser algo mais puxado para quem não tem boas bases de análise. Há que compreender muito bem a topologia e as noções métricas de $\mathbb{R}^N$ para nos podermos abstrair em espaços métricos mais gerais. Ou seja, é um livro para quem já está minimamente confortável com os conceitos centrais da análise. Portanto recomendo leres depois de te sentires assim, seja em que livro pegares antes

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela paciência.

Answer (score 1):

The way a math book is written for math students might not make it suitable for physics students. In any case, take a look at Appel's [*Mathematics for Physics and Physicists*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691131023/mathematics-for-physics-and-physicists).